# Function returning a 2d-array-- abort trap 6

Tags: c, function

I'm writing a simple program taking a double `alpha` and integer `deg` that prints a matrix `mat` as computed by `create_basis`. Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 30

void create_basis(uint64_t mat[][MAX],double alpha, int deg);

void create_basis(uint64_t mat[][MAX],double alpha,int deg){

    int i;
    int j;

    for(i=0;i<deg+1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<deg+2;j++)
            mat[i][j]=0;        
    }

    for(i=0;i<deg+1;i++){
        mat[i][deg+1]=floor(pow(alpha,i)*pow(10,16));
        mat[i][i]=1;
    }
}

int main(){
    int deg;
    double alpha;
    int i;
    int j;

    printf("Enter number:\n");
    scanf("%lf",&alpha);
    printf("Enter degree:\n");
    scanf("%d",&deg);

    uint64_t mat[deg+1][deg+2];
    create_basis(mat,alpha,deg);

    printf("Matrix basis=\n\n");
    for(i=0;i<deg+1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<deg+2;j++){
            if(j==0)
                printf("[%llu ",mat[i][j]);
            if(j==deg+1)
                printf("%llu]",mat[i][j]);
            else
                printf("%llu ",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run, there seems to be an issue when I call `create_basis` in `main` because it is giving an `abort trap 6` error, which I presume to mean I'm trying to access memory I don't have. However, the dimensions of `mat` seem to agree with what I'm trying to access. Am I calling `create_basis` incorrectly? Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use your debugger, it should help

Comment: When you use two-dimensional arrays like this, the second dimension must match in the caller and the callee.  In the caller you're declaring the second dimension as `deg+2`.  But in the `create_basis` function the second dimension is `MAX`.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, why is it that only the second dimension must match?

Comment: @gdavtor [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029930/passing-multidimesional-array-in-c-c). It may help explain in further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void create_basis(uint64_t mat[][MAX],double alpha,int deg){`
 change to
`void create_basis(int deg, uint64_t mat[deg+1][deg+2],double alpha){`

As reasons already explained @SteveSummit is
Two-dimensional array does not have to match.